# How to add multiple paths in Perl's Mojo::URL?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

How can I add multiple [`path`](https://docs.mojolicious.org/Mojo/URL#path)'s to a [`Mojo::URL`](https://docs.mojolicious.org/Mojo/URL) object? Consider the example below:

```perl
perl -Mojo -E 'say new Mojo::URL("https://httpbin.org/")->path("bytes")->path($_)->to_abs for (1..3)'
```

Desired output:

```
https://httpbin.org/bytes/1
https://httpbin.org/bytes/2
https://httpbin.org/bytes/3
```

Actual output:

```
https://httpbin.org/1
https://httpbin.org/2
https://httpbin.org/3
```

Doing `->path("bytes/$_")` seems wrong.

Comment: Thank you @SteffenUllrich for clarifying. You are correct. I'm constructing the URL from multiple variables, and I thought concatenating with `/` is not ideal. Even this doesn't work: `->path("bytes",$_)`. You may post your response as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example *almost* works, but the problem is that

```
Mojo::URL->new("https://httpbin.org/")->path("bytes")
```

constructs the URL `https://httpbin.org/bytes`, which has a "base" of `https://httpbin.org/`. When you do `->path("1")` on it, that's resolved relative to the base, which means that `1` *replaces* `bytes`.

Instead if you do

```
Mojo::URL->new("https://httpbin.org/")->path("bytes/")->path("$_")
```

with an added `/`, you get exactly the result you wanted.

This is because something that's constructing an HTTP URL doesn't know what's a "directory" and what isn't unless the URL makes it clear with a slash. That's why webservers traditionally redirect you to a URL ending in a slash if you access a directory's path without the trailing slash.

Answer (score 1):

Use a combination of Mojo::URL and Path::Tiny

```
use Mojo::URL;
use Path::Tiny qw/path/;
use feature 'say';

say Mojo::URL->new('https://httpbin.org/')
             ->path( path(bytes => $_ )->stringify )
             ->to_abs
    for (1..3);
```